# how to echo the first value of a GROUP BY in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I hava a table like this

```
|Rank|Location|Item Sold|Success|Failed|
|--------------------------------------|
|1   |Mall    |7        |5      |2     |
|2   |School  |5        |2      |3     |
|3   |Office  |4        |0      |4     |
```

What I want to happen is to get the highest number of items sold, in this case it is 7 and then echo it. The result that I am aiming for is this

```
 Most number of items sold for the day: 7
|Rank|Location|Item Sold|Success|Failed|
|--------------------------------------|
|1   |Mall    |7        |5      |2     |
|2   |School  |5        |2      |3     |
|3   |Office  |4        |0      |4     |
```

I don't know how to do this

This is the sql code that I used to get the data from the database is this

```
<?php
            $sql = "SELECT location, COUNT(*) as itemsold,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Success,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
            FROM inventory  
            LEFT JOIN inventorydetails ON inventory.leadid = inventorydetails.leadid
            GROUP BY location 
            ORDER BY itemsold DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        ?>
```

and this is the code that I used to create the table and then populate the table with the information from the database

```
        <table border ="5" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Rank</td>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>Item Sold</td>
                <td>Success</td>
                <td>Failed</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $i = 1;
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[location]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[itemsold]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[Success]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[Failed]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
                   $i=$i+1;
                   }

            ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: i am not getting any error, the table is working fine. I just want to get the highest number of item sold

Comment: since you're ordering, the first row you fetch out will be the highest. so fetch that, display the header, THEN start your table loop, but use a `do .. while` instead of a while.

Comment: if i used a do..while, it will print an empty row in the table first before proceeding to printing the result of the rest of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should do the trick. The premise is simple. Get your first row, and if it exists, echo out your header row.

Then print the table header.

Then again if you have data, execute a loop which populates the table rows.

```
    <?php
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($row) {
      echo "Most number of items sold for the day: {$row['itemsold']}";
    } ?>
    <table border ="5" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Rank</td>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td>Item Sold</td>
            <td>Success</td>
            <td>Failed</td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        if($row) {
        $i = 1;
        do {              
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row[location]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row[itemsold]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row[Success]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row[Failed]."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
               $i=$i+1;
        } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));

      } // close the if. ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: You may want to correct your code. There is no such thing as `$row['itemssold']`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the max value via SQL you may do the following

```
select max(itemsold) from (
(
    SELECT location, COUNT(*) as itemsold,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Success,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
            FROM inventory  
            LEFT JOIN inventorydetails ON inventory.leadid = inventorydetails.leadid
            GROUP BY location 
            ORDER BY itemsold DESC
)
```

If you want to get the max value via the returned $result, you can store all the rows into an array first, find the max value to print, and then output the table using the array in the end.

Comment: sorry, i dont get what your trying to say :(